# Custom regex validation for mobile phones issue in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build my regex to validate phone numbers. These are the rules:

1. Telephones should not contain any characters except `numbers` and `+`
2. Other strings which doesn't start with `06` or `+316` or `0316` or `00316` are invalid.

This is what I tried:
`$telephone = preg_replace('/[^0-9+]/','', $telephone);`

removes all characters except `+` and `numbers` . Here still I need to check if the `+` is the first character or not. For example `466116+` or `21323+3122` are invalid.

`preg_match('/^(06|+316)/i', $telephone)` . I am trying here to add the starting conditions , but it doesn't work . Could you please help me out?  I am lost with regex :| Thank you

Comment: Hi @Wiktor , if it is duplicated how can I add those conditions with the starting strings ?

Comment: If you put the ^ inside the bracket it is taken litteraly, you need to put it outside like `/^[0-9+]/` to check if the first character is a number or the + char. It doesnt solve totally your problem but it's a start.

Comment: `+` is a special char that must be escaped in a regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am talking about : `06 or +316 or 0316 or 00316` these parts :) thnx

Comment: what's an example of a valid number, not a part of a valid number. how bout an in-valid number.

Comment: You have `'/^(06|\+316)/i'`, just add other alternatives.

Comment: Why is it case insensitive again?  `/../i` Because yea those uppercase digits are tricky....

Comment: `+403132136420430+` this will output `403132136420430+` and it should be `+403132136420430` if I am using this `/^[0-9+]/`

Comment: Use the following regex:

`^(06\d{a}|\+316\d{b}|0316\d{c}|00316\d{d})`

where a,b,c,d should be replaced by the exact number of digits allowed following your different initial formats.

Comment: Why do you want to preg replace letters for example? I mean just because you remove an "r" from a string doesn't mean the phone number is valid. It could be the user wanted to press 3 or 4 and accidentally pressed "r". Removing the "r" does not mean it's correct. Why not send it back to user and say "you made a mistake, please verify".